# how to get a list of US State Names from us 1.0.0 package?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to use this [us 1.0.0 package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/us) to get a list of US State Names, but come across something I don't quite understand. Here's my code:

```
import us
lst= us.states.STATES_AND_TERRITORIES
type(lst) # output: list
type(lst[0]) # output: us.states.State
lst[0] # output: <State:Alabama>
'<State:Alabama>' == list[0] # output: False
```

The very last line confused the most. Why it is False? I thought they look exactly the same...

Anyway, my question is, how could I use this package to make a list of States names, so that I can check if one string is a state name or not, like:

```
if 'string_to_check' in lst:
    do something...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<State:Alabama>` is just the *string representation* of the `State`. The list item itself is *not* a string, but of type `us.states.State`, as you saw two lines earlier.

I did not try it, but according to the documentation of that package, to get a list of all the state names, a list comprehension like the following should work:

```
state_names = [state.name for state in us.states.STATES_AND_TERRITORIES]
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I need! Thank you @tobias_k